# Blank screen or cannot find symbol error while drawing car

Tags: swing, graphics, awt

I'm working on a project to animate a car moving across the across the screen.  I got the car made but then when I edited the code so I could call the car multiple times (putting it inside of a class), it now just gives me either a blank screen or 'cannot find symbol paintComponent' error.  Putting it as:

- super.paintComponent(g) tells me cannot find symbol.
- drawCar.super.paintComponent(g) tells me cannot find symbol. (tried this after looking at other errors).
- drawCar.paintComponent(g) tells me "error: non-static method paintComponent(Graphics) cannot be referenced from a static context"
- paintComponent(g) compiles but gives me a blank screen.
- removing it completely compiles but gives me an blank screen.

Here's my code:

```
   import java.awt.Graphics;
   import java.awt.Polygon;
   import java.awt.Color;
   import javax.swing.*;


public class CarDriver extends JPanel
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new Car());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setSize(800, 800);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
   import java.awt.*;
   import javax.swing.*;

   public class Car extends JPanel
   {
       drawCar car = new drawCar(200);
       private static final int D_W = 400;
       private static final int D_H = 400;


    public class drawCar
    {
        private static final int INCREMENT = 5;
        int x;

        public drawCar(int x)
        {
            x = x;
        }

    public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        drawCar.paintComponent(g);
       // body of the car
       g.setColor(Color.blue);
       int xValues[] = { x + 80, x + 80, x + 180, x + 180};
       int yValues[] = { 60, 120, 120, 60};
       Polygon polygon1 = new Polygon( xValues, yValues, 4 );
       g.fillPolygon( polygon1 );

        //hood / front end of car
       int xValues2[] = {x + 180, x + 200, x + 200};
       int yValues2[] = {60, 60, 90};
       g.drawPolyline( xValues2, yValues2, 3);
       int xValues2a[] = {x + 180, x + 180, x + 220, x + 220};
       int yValues2a[] = {90, 120, 120, 90};
       Polygon polygon3 = new Polygon( xValues2a, yValues2a, 4);
       g.fillPolygon ( polygon3);

       //cartop
       g.setColor(Color.black);
       int xValues3[] = {x + 90, x + 90, x +  170, x + 170};
       int yValues3[] = {45, 60, 60, 45};
       Polygon polygon2 = new Polygon(xValues3, yValues3, 4);
       g.fillPolygon(polygon2);

        //wheels
       g.fillOval(x + 80, 100, 35, 35);
       g.fillOval(x + 180, 100, 35, 35);


    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: `paintComponent` is a protected method of `JPanel` and you can't call it directly, nor should you

Comment: Your `paintComponent` is a method of `drawCar`, no super class has a method called `paintComponent`, so you can't use `super.paintComponent`.  Adding `Car` to anything won't paint anything because you don't' paint anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a closer look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for a better understanding of how painting works.

Your `paintComponent` method is a method of `drawCar`, but `drawCar` doesn't extend from anything which would be paintable (like `JComponent`)

Instead, you should make `drawCar` a separate class which has a simple "paint" method, for example...

```
public class Car {

    private static final int INCREMENT = 5;
    int x;

    public Car(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // body of the car
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        int xValues[] = {x + 80, x + 80, x + 180, x + 180};
        int yValues[] = {60, 120, 120, 60};
        Polygon polygon1 = new Polygon(xValues, yValues, 4);
        g.fillPolygon(polygon1);

        //hood / front end of car
        int xValues2[] = {x + 180, x + 200, x + 200};
        int yValues2[] = {60, 60, 90};
        g.drawPolyline(xValues2, yValues2, 3);
        int xValues2a[] = {x + 180, x + 180, x + 220, x + 220};
        int yValues2a[] = {90, 120, 120, 90};
        Polygon polygon3 = new Polygon(xValues2a, yValues2a, 4);
        g.fillPolygon(polygon3);

        //cartop
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        int xValues3[] = {x + 90, x + 90, x + 170, x + 170};
        int yValues3[] = {45, 60, 60, 45};
        Polygon polygon2 = new Polygon(xValues3, yValues3, 4);
        g.fillPolygon(polygon2);

        //wheels
        g.fillOval(x + 80, 100, 35, 35);
        g.fillOval(x + 180, 100, 35, 35);

    }
}
```

then you can create a component capable of actually painting it, for example...

```
public class CarPane extends JPanel {

    Car car = new Car(200);
    private static final int D_W = 400;
    private static final int D_H = 400;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        car.paint(g);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
    }

}
```

[image: Car]

Now, this means you can have as many instances of `Car` as you like and make `CarPane` paint them (by adding them into a `List` and having the `CarPane`'s `paintComponent` method iterate over it)

What I would strongly suggest, is you concentrate on setting up the basic properties of the car with it's origin point at `0x0`, then use `Graphics2D` and a `AffineTransform` to physical change the location at which it is painted, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418111/how-to-move-polygon-object-with-keylistener-in-java/35419959#35419959).

This will greatly improve the performance and reduce the overall complexity

Comment: Thank you!  That helped so much.  I'm also reading over the links you gave me before moving onto the next part (making the car move across the screen).